# Blank Minimap for IFC and NWC files

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have enabled minimap feature in my viewer, but it shows the map only for Revit files. For other file formats like NWC and IFC I only see a blank minimap window. Is the feature supported for these file format? If yes, how do I get it to work for these formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Minimap extension requires some additional information extracted from the design. In a Model Derivative manifest, look for something like this:

```
...
{
    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJ.../output/Resource/AECModelData.json",
    "role": "Autodesk.AEC.ModelData",
    "mime": "application/json",
    "guid": "a4aac952-a3f4-031c-4113-b2d9ac2d0de6",
    "type": "resource",
    "status": "success"
},
...
```

I'm afraid that currently the AEC Model Data is only extracted from Revit models.

Comment: is there any way to add the data manually?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's possible today.